# Fastshap summary plot - Error: can't combine <double> and <factor<919a3>>

Tags: r, summary, shap

I'm trying to get a summary plot using fastshap explain function as in the code below.

```
p_function_G<- function(object, newdata)
  caret::predict.train(object,
                       newdata = 
                       newdata,
                       type = "prob")[,"AntiSocial"] # select G class




# Calculate the Shapley values
#
# boostFit: is a caret model using catboost algorithm
# trainset: is the dataset used for bulding the caret model.
#   The dataset contains 4 categories W,G,R,GM
#    corresponding to 4 diferent animal  behaviors
library(caret)

shap_values_G <- fastshap::explain(xgb_fit,
                  X = game_train,                   
                  pred_wrapper = 
                  p_function_G,
                  nsim = 50,
                  newdata= game_train[which(game_test=="AntiSocial"),])
)
```

However I'm getting error

Error in 'stop_vctrs()':
can't combine latitude  and gender <factor<919a3>>

What's the way out?

Comment: Hi, is this based on the tutorial here? https://juliasilge.com/blog/board-games/

Comment: Yes, it is based on the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are adapting code from Julia Silge's [Predict ratings for board games](https://juliasilge.com/blog/board-games) Tutorial. The original code used [SHAPforxgboost](https://liuyanguu.github.io/SHAPforxgboost/) for generating SHAP values, but you're using the [fastshap](https://bgreenwell.github.io/fastshap/articles/fastshap.html) package.

Because Shapley explanations are only recently starting to gain traction, there aren't very many *standard* data formats. `fastshap` does not like [tidyverse tibble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/)s, it only takes matrices or matrix-likes.

The error occurs because, by default, `fastshap` attempts to convert the tibble to a matrix. But this fails, because matrices can only have one type (f.x. either double or factor, not both).

I also ran into a similar issue and found that you can solve this by passing the `X` parameter as a [data.frame](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/data.frame). I don't have access to your full code but you could you try replacing the `shap_values_G` code-block as so:

```
shap_values_G <- fastshap::explain(xgb_fit,
                  X = game_train,                   
                  pred_wrapper = 
                  p_function_G,
                  nsim = 50,
                  newdata= as.data.frame(game_train[which(game_test=="AntiSocial"),]))
)
```

Wrap `newdata` with `as.data.frame`. This converts the tibble to a dataframe and so shouldn't upset `fastshap`.